# Making objects smooth via Blender vs. OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, 3d

I'm creating models in Blender as polygon meshes and trying to load and use these models in OpenGL as `.obj` and `.ctm`.

My question is what is the common sense to make objects smooth in OpenGL applications? Making smooth the model in blender and then exporting it as `.obj` or exporting the models as is and then making smooth them in OpenGL?

I don't mean smooth line, I want to make the whole object smooth [as below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRzMV.jpg).

Obviously, making smooth in Blender increases file size, vertex count etc. and making smooth in OpenGL requires more processing. However, I'm not sure about whether making smooth in OpenGL is possible or not. For example I've tried below code but it didn't help me to make my model smooth.

```
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); 
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_FASTEST); 
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Your smooth "below image" has nothing to do with anything that would increase "file size, vertex count etc". It comes entirely from applying normals to the existing vertices and performing lighting computations. So it's not clear if you're talking about lighting or *tessellation*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to review some tutorials about different shader models.
Smooth shaders will interpolate the color of your faces whereas solid shaders will render each face on a single color. Some times using smooth shaders can create the illusion of smooth objects alone and the computation cost is usually negligible. Depending on the object you may need to add some vertices before exporting to achieve the smooth look once rendered.

Google brought up this result, I bet there are many other tutorials you can look into.
http://xoax.net/cpp/crs/opengl/lessons/Lesson5/

Comment: Thnaks a lot Josep. Your answer and tutorial link really helped me so much.